# How to Retrain Sequence to Sequence Neural Network model for Language Translation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, language-translation, seq2seq

I have trained a seq2seq tensorflow model for translating a sentence from English to Spanish. I trained a model for 615 700 steps, and save the model checkpoints successfully. My training data size for both English and Spanish sentences is 200 000. I want to retrain this model for 10K new data sentences from 615 700 steps. I am using sequence to sequence tensoflow model for this. How can I start retrain model from the last checkpoint? [Here](https://github.com/MonicaVillanueva/English_Spanish_Translator) is the link that I am usingfor the translation.

I have 3 types of files in my train folder:

```
.index
.meta
.data
and checkpoint file.
```

My new training data set files are `europarl_train.es-en.en` and `europarl_train.es-en.es`for English and Spanish sentences respectively.

I write a code to load my model .meta file and weights

```
import data_utils
import seq2seq_model
import translate
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:    
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/home/i9/L-T_Model_Training/16_NOV_MODEL/train/translate.ckpt-615700.meta')
    saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/home/i9/L-T_Model_Training/16_NOV_MODEL/train/.'))
```

How can I start retaining for this dataset?

Answer (score 0):

**Save**

According to [TensorFlow version 2 doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/CheckpointManager) you can use `tf.train.Checkpoint` and `tf.train.CheckpointManager` class for saving your Model.
Consider the following example:

```
checkpoint_dir = './training_checkpoints'       # custom directory
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt")
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(model=model)   # your model variable name
manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(checkpoint=checkpoint, directory=checkpoint_dir, max_to_keep=3)           # max_to_keep means how much of last checkpoints number you like to keep
```

Now if you like to save your model type this: `manager.save()`

**Load**

Define checkpoint and checkpointManager again and run this code:

```
if manager.latest_checkpoint:
    checkpoint.restore((manager.latest_checkpoint)).assert_consumed()
    print("Restored from {}".format(manager.latest_checkpoint))
```

If you got an error like (AssertionError: Unresolved object in checkpoint (root)) replace `assert_consumed` with `expect_partial`. (go here for the difference: [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint#restore) )

The model has loaded from the checkpoint.
Now you can load your data and fix the shapes and continue training your model.